# extending Bash tab completion: how to handle paths / partial commands?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I've added tab completion for my program to bash. It works quite well, but I don't know how to handle partial completion of words.
Example: the user types

```
./program /home/user/De
```

and presses TAB. This is then completed to

```
./program /home/user/Desktop/
```

, but there's now a trailing whitespace after 'Desktop/', which is not what I want. Basically, I need a way of preventing bash from adding whitespace after the completed word.

I don't want to use bash's completion for paths.

**Edit:** This seems to be unclear. When TAB is pressed, my tab-completion function finds out which word to complete (in this case, that's '/home/user/De'). It then generates a list of matches (in this case, the only match is '/home/user/Desktop'). Bash uses this list to do the actual completion: It changes '/home/user/De' to '/home/user/Desktop/ '. I want to prevent bash from adding that whitespace after 'Desktop/'.

Comment: Please post your bash completion script, if @vahid's hint http://stackoverflow.com/q/10129747/1741542 doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

tried it in speech marks ?

```
./program "/home/user/[tab]"
```

am unsure about this question in total :) bash actually does the auto completion am unsure how you have written a script that auto completes something that bash does for u -

anyhow...  you have stated you don't want bash to add extra space - unless you plan to rewrite bash or add to it - this won't be possible

Instead this is something u need to add to your own code to remove white spaces.  try

```
var1=${var1//[[:space:]]}
```

after getting the value in where var1 is variable name for input

Comment: Same thing happens. Anyway, that's not something I can control - it's up to whoever's typing that to type it correctly. I'd like to make this easy for users.

Comment: Bash has a "Programmable Completion", see `man bash`. You can extend it specifically for commands, so that it expands to whatever you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129747/conditional-trailing-space-with-bash-programmable-completion think its already answered here

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks!
Edit: Now, how do I mark this as solved?